# Datagrid binding with LINQ results? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid

I am trying to bind(no code behind =)) my datagridview from my example WPF Application with my results of my LINQ. It must be pretty easy but I am missing it "somehow" somewhere. Some things you must consider: First of all I am using an ORACLE db and I have successfully made the mappings, I am having this result:

```
     this.SearchCommand = new RelayCommand(this.DisplayMessage, CanDisplayMessage);
    }


    public bool CanDisplayMessage()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void DisplayMessage()
    {
       using ( Entities ctx = new Entities())
        {
            var query = from e in ctx.EMPLOYEES select new { e.EMPLOYEE_ID,e.FIRST_NAME,
                         e.LAST_NAME, e.EMAIL, e.PHONE_NUMBER,
                         e.SALARY, e.DEPARTMENT_ID};

         var results = query.ToList();
        }
    }
```

http://s27.postimg.org/ya0crw701/linqresults.jpg

I know that I have to bind my Datagrid with an Itemssource, as I have always have made it. I used an ObservableCollection to bind my results from my DataReader (with normal Sql Commands...) with my DataGrid. Now my XAML looks like this:

```
   <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee ID"    Binding="{Binding Path= EMPLOYEE_ID}"/> 
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name"     Binding="{Binding Path= FIRST_NAME}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name"      Binding="{Binding Path= LAST_NUMBER}"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Email"          Binding="{Binding Path= EMAIL}"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Phone number"   Binding="{Binding Path= PHONE_NUMBER}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Salary"         Binding="{Binding Path= SALARY}"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Department ID"  Binding="{Binding Path= DEPARTMENT_ID}"  />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

http://s29.postimg.org/or9jhxuau/xaml.jpg

I have tried to bind my Results from my LINQ:

```
  public void DisplayMessage()
    {
       using ( Entities ctx = new Entities())
        {
            var query = from e in ctx.EMPLOYEES select new { e.EMPLOYEE_ID,e.FIRST_NAME,
                         e.LAST_NAME, e.EMAIL, e.PHONE_NUMBER,
                         e.SALARY, e.DEPARTMENT_ID};

         var results = query.ToList();

        }
    }
```

with my datagrid but nothing is coming back! I have tried to bind an Observerable Collection with this result but I am having an Error. What I am missing here? What I have to write on ItemsSource of my DataGrid so I can bind the the Datagrid with my results?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what error you have got??

Comment: please post your actual code, the `DisplayMessage()` does something but ***useless*** here, the result is saved into the local variable `results` without any further usage. So how could it be used outside?

Comment: Why a jpg of xaml?  Post the xaml.

Comment: thats my problem how I can use the results to bind it with my datagrid, DisplayMessage() is the method that I am using for my Command, If you press Search then this Method will execute the LINQ statement show I can show on my DataGrid my Results,

Comment: Look up .net wpf binding on msdn.microsoft.com.

Comment: I know how the binding works Bl4m the problem is that all the paradgims are showing how i can bind a Datagrid on code behind, I am using the mvvm model for this project and i was wondering how I am going to bind it without an observablecollection if i bind the results nothing is coming, thats why I thought that some one will give me an answer or an example on how to do it properly thanks for your consider

Comment: create a property of type `IEnumerable` in your view model and store the result of the query in that property. (e.g. `this.Results = query.ToList();`). Then just bind to that property `{Binding Results}`

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<EMPLOYEE>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) I have tried that before but this comes up

Answer (score 3):

Where do you populate the gridview?
Maybe this work ...

```
public void DisplayMessage()
{
   using ( Entities ctx = new Entities())
    {
        var query = from e in ctx.EMPLOYEES select new {  e.EMPLOYEE_ID,e.FIRST_NAME,
                     e.LAST_NAME, e.EMAIL, e.PHONE_NUMBER,
                     e.SALARY, e.DEPARTMENT_ID};

     var results = query.ToList();
     gridview.DataSource = results;
     gridview.Databind();
    }
}
```

You have to set an id here

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ID="gridview" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
< DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=results}">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee ID"    Binding="{Binding EMPLOYEE_ID}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Items to be bind should be presented like public properties of ItemsSource